# I am facing difficulties to set parameters in power BI reports and in dashboards also

Tags: powerbi

Currently, I'm using the Power BI Designer (newest version). I'm completely new to it. I'm wondering how to set a parameters in reports and dashboards.So please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Open your report in Power BI desktop application, then go to tab:“Manage Parameters” dialog in the Query Editor window.

[image]

and into that dialog you can create new parameters and specify metadata and settings for new parameter:

[image]

After defining one or more parameters and clicking OK in the “Manage Parameters” dialog, users will get back to the Query Editor dialog and will see a new query defined for each parameter. Then, that parameter can be referenced from appropriate query.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, reports support filters that you can set in the filters pane.  Dashboards do not support filtering.  Supporting more traditional parameters is something we're looking at.  Suggest you create an idea on support.powerbi.com so we can keep you updated.